# Annotation cache grails

Tags: grails, caching, groovy

We have a liveticker with lots of games, now we have a problem with the cache is not effective.

Short example:

```
Class Ticker {
    @Cacheable(cache = "liveTickerGameCache")
    def table = {
        cache validFor: 120
        def competition = Competition.get(params.id)
        render(template:"table", model:[competition:competition])
    }
}
```

1 Person open a game /live-ticker/182 and now the table will cache in the liveTickerGame.

2 Person open a game /live-ticker/183 -> cache into the liveTickerGame

So the problem, if a new event is comming we clear the complete liveTickerGameCache

```
private clearGameCache(Game game) {
    // TODO: clear related cache entries
    springcacheService.flush('liveTickerGameCache')
}
```

Is it possible to delete a element in the liveTickerGameCache or create for every game a unique liveTickerGameCache?

Grails Version:1.3.7

Comment: why `if a new event is comming we clear the complete liveTickerGameCache`?

Comment: What plugin are you using with Grails for caching?

Comment: @injecteer because we want to see as fast as possible the event on the page

Comment: @JoshuaMoore
echache , cache-headers 1.1.5

Comment: and what is the problem with "effectiveness"? is it taking too much time to flush/refill or what?

Comment: okay sry.

we have 50 games running. the problem is if one game get a new event , he delete the complete cache. 
i want to have for every game a own cache , is this possible?

Comment: You really should consider using http://grails.org/plugin/cache instead to cache the data that your controller uses instead of caching the result from the controller call. That way you can expire specific entries in the cache instead of the entire collection.

Comment: can you give me some example for this?